# is google street view api now using the subscription method?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-street-view

I tried google street view api on my application a few years ago, and it works as I wish, but this week I used the same code and tried to use google street view api, but it didn't work, "Oops! Something went wrong"

and when I check logcat it says:

```
2019-10-04 09:49:23.832 28904-28904/com.ionlab.project.volley E/Google Maps Android API: The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application. This might be because of an incorrectly configured project, or an invalid API key. See the Google API console: https://console.developers.google.com, and information about Obtaining an API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup.
```

even though my API configuration is correct

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered your new project to Google API Console.

**Google Maps Android API: The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application.**

==> This indicates that you have to enable your `MAP API for android` from your API console. Also enable `StreetView Service` from your `API Console`